# How can we resolve "Cannot Edit an Item Outside of the transaction" in LightSwitch?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

Error: How can we resolve **"Cannot Edit an Item Outside of the transaction"** in LightSwitch?

[image]

**Solution:** Please your solution and reopen it.

for more detail please [click here](http://harshgupta71.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-can-we-resolve-cannot-edit-item.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found this error occurs after updating an external data source particularly RIA services. The only workaround I have found is to delete the data source and reimport it with a different name.